Laravel blade component merge class dynamically
I created a button component with laravel 11 and tailwind. The weird thing is :When I assign its background color to different values, sometimes it displays the background color as expected, sometimes it doesn't show any background color! Particularly like 'bg-sky-900', 'bg-yellow-900',... Any clue what's happening? Thanks in advance:)
The button looks like this:
@props(['color'=>'sky-500')

<a href="#" {{$attributes->merge(['class'=>"px-2 py-1 text-white bg-".$color." border-none  focus:outline-none" ])}}>{{$slot}}</a>

and I use the button like this:

<x-btn color='sky-500' >Read more</x-btn>

Sometimes its background color is not displayed as expected like:"bg-sky-900", "bg-yellow-900",...

You seem to be missing a closing square bracket:
@props(['color'=>'sky-500'])
                          ↑
                        This

Regardless, as per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You could:

Have the entire class in the variable you pass as a prop, like
@props(['color'=>'bg-sky-500'])

<a href="#" {{$attributes->merge(['class'=>"px-2 py-1 text-white " . $color . " border-none  focus:outline-none" ])}}>{{$slot}}</a>

<x-btn color='bg-sky-500' >Read more</x-btn>


Have a dictionary for color to Tailwind class names:
@props(['color'=>'sky-500'])

@php
$background_colors = [
  'sky-500' => 'bg-sky-500',
  …
];
@endphp

<a href="#" {{$attributes->merge(['class'=>"px-2 py-1 text-white " . $background_colors[$color] . " border-none  focus:outline-none" ])}}>{{$slot}}</a>


safelist the classes, if you have a limited number of known colors:
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    { pattern: /^bg-(red|green|blue)-500$/ },
    // …
  ],
  // …
];



